# Calculate percentage between startTime, currentTime and endTime - python

Tags: python, time, percentage

I want to make a progress bar. To achieve this first i need percentage.

For example i watch the movie. i know when movie starts (startTime) and when ends (endTime).

`startTime = "09:40" currentTime = "11:52" endTime = "13:05"`

So i need to calculate current percentage of playing.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `(currentTime-startTime)*100/(endTime-startTime)` and extracting the numbers from the strings, and converting to minutes before this would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

timefmt = "%H:%M"
startTime = datetime.strptime("09:40", timefmt)
currentTime = datetime.strptime("11:52", timefmt)
endTime = datetime.strptime("13:05", timefmt)

ratio = (currentTime - startTime) / (endTime - startTime)
print(f"{ratio:5.2%}")
```

you can parse your strings into a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object; those can be subtracted (which will return a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object).

then just use sting formatting in order to print the ratio in percent.

---

for this to work in python 2.7 you need to call `total_seconds()` on the `timedelta` objects and replace the f-string with `str.format`:

```
ratio = (currentTime - startTime).total_seconds() / (endTime - startTime).total_seconds()
print("{:5.2%}".format(ratio))
```

Comment: Works perfectly in python 3, thanks. Is it possible to run on python 2.7 and python 3 as well?

Comment: the `datetime` module has been around for a long time. this should all work in python 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#module-datetime

Comment: Soory i forget to put the error here from 2.7:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.timedelta'`

Comment: oh, i see. added an update that should work.

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm now in 2.7 as well. Because i am little bit confused with python 2 syntax, can you just tell me please what should be an equivalent in py2 for this format? 
`print(f"{ratio:5.2%}")`

Comment: the equivalent to this f-string would be `"{:5.2%}".format(ratio)`. (not tested...)

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Big thx!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the `datetime` module as already mentioned in an answer, but this is a more brute-force or general approach and would work even if the time is in `HH:MM:SS` format

```
startTime = "09:40" 
currentTime = "11:52" 
endTime = "13:05"

def changeToMin(time):
    arr = list(map(int, time.split(':')))
    seconds = 0
    for n,i in enumerate(arr):
        seconds += i*60**(len(arr)-n-1)
    return seconds
    
def precentage(start, end, current):
    return (current-start)*100/(end-start)
    
print(precentage(changeToMin(startTime), changeToMin(endTime), changeToMin(currentTime)))
```

Comment: Works perfectly in python 2.7 and python 3. Yes it's a small brute-force but it's good. It is very important for me to work on 2.7 and 3.